# Pass variables into node.js function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to pass an additional variable (devicename) into session.pingHost so that only once the ping has returned a response do I run another function (someOtherFunction) which requires the variable. Currently someOtherFunction receives devicename as undefined.

How would I accomplish this? Is there a better way of doing it?

```
var ping = require("net-ping");
var pingresult = '';

pingDevice('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'My Device');

function pingDevice(ipaddress, devicename){

    var options = {
        retries: 1,
        timeout: 2000
    };

    var session = ping.createSession (options);

    session.pingHost (ipaddress, function (error, target) {

        if (error) {
            console.log (target + ": ping FAIL");
            pingresult = '0';
        } else {
            console.log (target + ": ping OK");
            pingresult = '1';
        }

        someOtherFunction(pingresult,devicename);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing it, using the fact that the callback is a closure over the context of the call to `pingDevice` (which contains the `devicename` argument), is entirely standard, normal practice. You can do exactly what you're doing, and given the code shown, it's what I would do.

*Another* way to do it is to use `Function#bind`:

```
session.pingHost (ipaddress, function (devicename, error, target) {
// ------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^

    if (error) {
        console.log (target + ": ping FAIL");
        pingresult = '0';
    } else {
        console.log (target + ": ping OK");
        pingresult = '1';
    }

    someOtherFunction(pingresult,devicename);

}.bind(null, devicename));
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`Function#bind` creates a new function that, when called, will call the original with a specific `this` value (we're not using that here, hence the `null`) and any arguments you give `bind`, followed by the arguments the new function was called with.

But I don't see any need for that here. The only real reason you'd need or want `bind` would be if you wanted to grab the value of `devicename` as of when you created the function (because it might change).

---

There is an *unrelated* problem: You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you don't declare your `pingresult` variable. Always be sure to declare your variables, in the appropriate context.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue is that when I do it like that and call someOtherFunction then devicename is undefined. ie. not passed into session.pingHost.

Comment: @sardaukar81: The value of `devicename` in `pingHost` will depend entirely on how you're calling `pingHost`, which you haven't shown. Provided you call `pingHost` with the correct value as the second argument, that same value will be used to call `someOtherFunction` later.

Comment: Hi TJ: I have updated my question as per your suggestions. The problem is that session.pingHost is part of the net-ping library so I cannot add additional arguments into it. I cannot figure out how to pass devicename to someOtherFunction through session.pingHost.

Comment: @sardaukar81: With that code, as of the call to `someOtherFunction`, `devicename` will definitely be `"My Device"`.

Comment: Hi TJ: You were right. There was an error in somOtherFunction. Thanks for your help.